# Zebra ZQ520 printer - how to advance to next label

Tags: printing, label, zebra-printers, zpl

I am working with a Zebra ZQ520 at the moment. I am printing on sticky labels. My problem is that the printer won't advance to the gap between labels when it has finished printing one label, which is what I need.

I have read about the JSA command and tried using it.

[https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zpl/JS_Command.pdf][1]

The sequence that I am sending to the printer looks something like this. The full sequence represents one label.

```
~JSA^XA^CWZ,E:TT0003M_.FNT^FS^XZ^XA^PA1,1,1,1^JUS^XZ....
```

I am not sure if I am inserting JSA at the right position or if it matters. I have tried ~JSB also but that doesn't seem to have any effect either.

Any tips of help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default the printer is in "Bar Sense", that is it is looking for a black bar printed on the back of the liner to use for calibration.  To put the printer in "Gap Sense" you need to send the following CPCL commands:

```
! DF CONFIG.SYS
! UTILITIES
GAP-SENSE
PRINT
```

After the printer is in the correct mode for bar or gap then run the followign command to calibrate:

```
~jc^xa^jus^xz
```

Also see the Zebra KB article on [Calibrating the ZQ and QL printers.](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8723)

Comment: : ! U1 setvar "media.printmode" "T"

Comment: Thanks very much Elton. I discovered the same. Have a good weekend.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered out what the issue was thankfully. The printer's *print mode* was not set to the correct value. I use the same printer for both continuous paper and sticky labels by the way.

For sticky labels, it needed to be set to *tear off* whereas it was in fact set to *rewind*.

I found the Zebra Android Setup Utility to be very useful in daignosing the issue. I now set the print mode *(media.printmode)* to the correct value at run time from my application's code.

@eltonsaunders Thanks very much for your assistance!